# How to retrieve the video details from a sitecore media item?

Tags: c#, sitecore

Here i am implementing video sitemap in my website and i am trying to get the details of the video in sitecore. I can able to read the details like title,description. But how to get the below details like duration,player location and other details mentioned below in XML

```xml
<video:video>
       <video:thumbnail_loc>http://www.example.com/thumbs/123.jpg</video:thumbnail_loc> 
       <video:title>Grilling steaks for summer</video:title>
       <video:description>Alkis shows you how to get perfectly done steaks every            
         time</video:description>
       <video:content_loc>http://www.example.com/video123.flv</video:content_loc>
       <video:player_loc allow_embed="yes" autoplay="ap=1">
         http://www.example.com/videoplayer.swf?video=123</video:player_loc>
       <video:duration>600</video:duration>
       <video:expiration_date>2009-11-05T19:20:30+08:00</video:expiration_date>
       <video:rating>4.2</video:rating> 
       <video:view_count>12345</video:view_count>    
       <video:publication_date>2007-11-05T19:20:30+08:00</video:publication_date>
       <video:family_friendly>yes</video:family_friendly>   
       <video:restriction relationship="allow">IE GB US CA</video:restriction> 
       <video:gallery_loc title="Cooking Videos">http://cooking.example.com</video:gallery_loc>
       <video:price currency="EUR">1.99</video:price>
       <video:requires_subscription>yes</video:requires_subscription>
       <video:uploader info="http://www.example.com/users/grillymcgrillerson">GrillyMcGrillerson
         </video:uploader>
       <video:live>no</video:live>
     </video:video>
```

Here is my code:

```
HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument document = htmlWeb.Load("http://www.example.com/us/cars/new-models/xc60");
var urls = document.DocumentNode.Descendants("source")
           .Select(x => x.Attributes[1].Value).ToList();
DynamicLink dynamicLink;
_videoval = new Videodetails();
foreach (var singleurl in urls)
    {
      if (!DynamicLink.TryParse(singleurl, out dynamicLink))
      return;
      MediaItem mediaItem = Sitecore.Context.Database.GetItem(dynamicLink.ItemId, dynamicLink.Language ?? Sitecore.Context.Language);
      var videodetail = new Videodetails() { Title = mediaItem.Title,Description = mediaItem.Description };
      videolist.Add(videodetail);
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sitecore doesn't read or store meta data about video files in the media library. So you need to retrieve the attached video file from the media item and read the metadata yourself.

I found a fairly simple and decent blog post about reading the duration of a videofile http://www.levibotelho.com/development/get-the-length-of-a-video-in-c/ and I am sure you can find some sort of .NET library for extracting any additional data that you require.

Cheers, Bo

Comment: How about thumbnail location?

Comment: Hi Rooney, I don't think that the thumbnail location is a standard part of the metadata in all video formats. Your best bet is to use some kind of library to extract a frame from the video - try taking a look at http://www.nrecosite.com/video_converter_net.aspx

Comment: [Are answers that just contain links elsewhere really “good answers”?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8231/are-answers-that-just-contain-links-elsewhere-really-good-answers)